# laravel route group closure always executing

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with Laravel route groups.Laravel always executing closure in `Route::group` method. Consider these two routes:

This is declared in routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'],function(){
  echo 'posts page';
});


Route::get('home'),function(){
  echo 'home page';
});
```

When i open `www.example.com/home`, the closure in `Route::group` executes.

So i am getting this output:

`posts page home page`

Logically i should get only `home page` as output

Comment: maybe it's declared in the middleware or kernel (etc)? Or probably RouteServiceProvider

Comment: This is declared in routes/web.php

Comment: You never stated that in your question

Comment: OK i added.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour.

`Route::group` is a helper/wrapper for a group of `Route::get/post`.

Every `Route::get/post` (not callback, just initialization) should be executed to create a list of routes.

Also, `Route::group` does not support parameters as get/post:

```
// Does not work!
Route::group(['prefix' =>'user/{id}'], function ($id) {
    Route::get('view', function() {});
    Route::post('update', function() {});
});

// Works
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user/{id}'], function () {
    Route::get('view', function($id) {});
    Route::post('update', function($id) {});
});
```

First of all, `routes/web.php` does not parse requests **directly**. It **builds** a list of all available routes.

It means that **every** `Route::get/post`(even inside group) should be executed and add rules/variables.

`Route::group` is a helper and it just adds extra parameters to internal get/post calls.

Second, when routes list is ready, kernel finds a proper callback/closure and executes it.

In other (rough) words `Route::group` add its 1st parameter to each Route::get/post inside.

Comment: Yes but when defined route and current url are not match, why closure executes ?
Also these routes are wrong. `Route::group` first argument must be array

Comment: Thanks, i updated group syntax. Group's callback is different comparing to Route::get/post. They have different goals.

Comment: Logically when first argument is false, second argument shouldn't execute.

Comment: No, laravel builds full list of routes. If group's callback won't be executed - you'll never know about internal routes. You shouldn't think that group's callback equal to route's callback. They looks similar, but have different goals.

Comment: Thanks. got it ;)